# String to float conversion issue in google cloud platform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gcloud

I have some categorical variables in the input instances for testing model in Gcloud. sklearn prediction unable to convert categorical string to float in Gcloud even it is working perfectly in local system.
Input Instance:

```
instances = [
    ["880409000000", 33, 51000111,"Female"]
    ]
```

Calling Function:

```
def predict(instances, **kwargs):
            inputs = np.asarray(instances)
            KVgender = {'male': 1, 'female': 2}
            inputs[:,3] = [KVgender[str.lower(item)] for item in inputs[:,3]]
            inputF = np.float64(inputs)
            return inputF
```

Error:

```py
Traceback: { "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during sklearn prediction: could not convert string to float: 'Female'" }
```

Local Software Versions:

- Python: 3.8.5
- scikit-learn: 0.23.1

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in GCP? If so, can you add the traceback in the question? Are you sure the versions are same in local and GCP?

Comment: Traceback: {
  "error": "Prediction failed: Exception during sklearn prediction: could not convert string to float: 'Female'"
}

Local python version: 3.8.5, scikit-learn: 0.23.1

Comment: Is the `scikit-learn` version in your local and in GCP same?

Comment: Yes, it is same.

Comment: Can you please share the code for the saved model and AI Platform run-time version that you are trying to use in the script? Because, this might be due to some dependencies between the package and runtime versions. The GCP AI platform supports Python version till 3.7, and you are using Python:3.8.5.  As per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list), you should use Python version 3.7 and run-time version 2.2 for  Scikit-learn:0.23.1 package.  So, if you share the above details, It will help me give a better solution.